# Spring Integration - Priority aggregator

Tags: spring, spring-integration, spring-amqp

I have following app requirements:

- Messages are received from RabbitMq, and then aggregated based on some more complex rules e.g. - based on `types` property (with pre-given type-time mapping) and based on existing time message has been waiting in the queue (`old` property)
- All messages should be released at some variable message rate, e.g. 1msg/sec up to 100msg/sec. This rate is controlled and set by service that will monitor rabbitmq queue size (one queue that is not related to this component, and is further up the pipeline) and if too much messages are in queue - would decrease the rate.

As you can see in the image one use-case: three messages are already aggregated and are waiting to be released next second (since current rate is `1msg/sec`), but just at that time, `MSG` arrives with `id:10`, and it updated `AGGREGATED 2`, making it become 1st message by priority. So on next tick, instead of releasing `AGGREGATED 3`, we release `AGGREGATED 2` since it has now higher priority.

[image]

Now, the question is - can I use Spring Integration Aggregator for this, since I do not know if it supports prioritization of messages during aggregation? I know of `groupTimeout`, but that one is only adjusting single message group - not changing priority of other groups. Would it be possible to use `MessageGroupStoreReaper` that would adjust all other aggregated messages by priority when new MSG arrives?

**UPDATE**

I did some implementation like this - seems OK for now - it is aggregating messages as it arrives, and comparator is sorting messages by my custom logic.

Do you think there could be some problems with this (concurrency etc.)? I can see in the logs, that poller is invoked more than once on occations. Is this normal?

```
2021-01-18 13:52:05.277  INFO 16080 --- [   scheduling-1] ggregatorConfig$PriorityAggregatingQueue : POLL
2021-01-18 13:52:05.277  INFO 16080 --- [   scheduling-1] ggregatorConfig$PriorityAggregatingQueue : POLL
2021-01-18 13:52:05.277  INFO 16080 --- [   scheduling-1] ggregatorConfig$PriorityAggregatingQueue : POLL
2021-01-18 13:52:05.277  INFO 16080 --- [   scheduling-1] ggregatorConfig$PriorityAggregatingQueue : POLL
```

Also, is this commented `doit` method, proper way to increase max number of polled messages in runtime?

```
@Bean
    public MessageChannel aggregatingChannel(){
        return new QueueChannel(new PriorityAggregatingQueue<>((m1, m2) -> {//aggr here},
                Comparator.comparingInt(x -> x),
                (m) -> {
                    ExampleDTO d = (ExampleDTO) m.getPayload();
                    return d.getId();
                }
        ));
    }

    class PriorityAggregatingQueue<K> extends AbstractQueue<Message<?>> {
        private final Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(getClass());
        private final BiFunction<Message<?>, Message<?>, Message<?>> accumulator;
        private final Function<Message<?>, K> keyExtractor;
        private final NavigableMap<K, Message<?>> keyToAggregatedMessage;

        public PriorityAggregatingQueue(BiFunction<Message<?>, Message<?>, Message<?>> accumulator,
                                        Comparator<? super K> comparator,
                                        Function<Message<?>, K> keyExtractor) {
            this.accumulator = accumulator;
            this.keyExtractor = keyExtractor;
            keyToAggregatedMessage = new ConcurrentSkipListMap<>(comparator);
        }

        @Override
        public Iterator<Message<?>> iterator() {
            return keyToAggregatedMessage.values().iterator();
        }

        @Override
        public int size() {
            return keyToAggregatedMessage.size();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean offer(Message<?> m) {
            logger.info("OFFER");
            return keyToAggregatedMessage.compute(keyExtractor.apply(m), (k,old) -> accumulator.apply(old, m)) != null;
        }

        @Override
        public Message<?> poll() {
            logger.info("POLL");
            Map.Entry<K, Message<?>> m = keyToAggregatedMessage.pollLastEntry();
            return m != null ? m.getValue() : null;
        }

        @Override
        public Message<?> peek() {
            Map.Entry<K, Message<?>> m = keyToAggregatedMessage.lastEntry();
            return m!= null ? m.getValue() : null;
        }
    }

//    @Scheduled(fixedDelay = 10*1000)
//    public void doit(){
//        System.out.println("INCREASE POLL");
//        pollerMetadata().setMaxMessagesPerPoll(pollerMetadata().getMaxMessagesPerPoll() * 2);
//    }

    @Bean(name = PollerMetadata.DEFAULT_POLLER)
    public PollerMetadata pollerMetadata(){
        PollerMetadata metadata = new PollerMetadata();
        metadata.setTrigger(new DynamicPeriodicTrigger(Duration.ofSeconds(30)));
        metadata.setMaxMessagesPerPoll(1);
        return metadata;
    }

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow aggregatingFlow(
            AmqpInboundChannelAdapter aggregatorInboundChannel,
            AmqpOutboundEndpoint aggregatorOutboundChannel,
            MessageChannel wtChannel,
            MessageChannel aggregatingChannel,
            PollerMetadata pollerMetadata
    ) {
    return IntegrationFlows.from(aggregatorInboundChannel)
        .wireTap(wtChannel)
        .channel(aggregatingChannel)
        .handle(aggregatorOutboundChannel)
        .get();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, if there is a new message for group to complete it arrives into an aggregator, then such a group is released immediately (if your `ReleaseStrategy` says that though). The rest of group under timeout will continue to wait for the schedule.

It is probably possible to come up with smart algorithm to rely on a single common schedule with the `MessageGroupStoreReaper` to decide if we need to release that partial group or just discard it. Again: the `ReleaseStrategy` should give us a clue to release or not, even if partial. When discard happens and we want to keep those messages in the aggregator, we need to resend them back to the aggregator after some delay. After expiration the group is removed from the store and this happens when we have already sent into a discard channel, so it is better to delay them and let an aggregator to clean up those groups, so after delay we can safely send them back to the aggregator for a new expiration period as parts of new groups.

You probably also can iterate all of the messages in the store after releases normal group to adjust some time key in their headers for the next expiration time.

I know this is hard matter, but there is really no any out-of-the-box solution since it was not designed to affect other groups from one we just dealt with...

Comment: The aggregator I need is actually only time based - so what is received in that timeframe it goes further - even if it is single mesaage. So I guess the only way to change groupTimeouts af all aggregated messages is some implementation as GroupReaper? From there I should have access to all the messages?

Comment: Well, you probably need to think about a custom `expireMessageGroups()` impl on the `AbstractMessageGroupStore` since that the place to decide which group to expire or not. The default one is to check group `timeout` or `lastModified` and decide how old is it.

Comment: How I imagine it will work is to schedule reaper component to run once per second, and then that reaper to decide which aggregated messages should be released at that point in time, out of all current messages in Message Store. If needed then, I would set that expireMessageGroups to never, so it is only decided in reaper.

Comment: No, reaper doesn't do that. It just calls this `this.messageGroupStore.expireMessageGroups(this.timeout);`. So, it is probably better to decide to expire group or not already there in that method impl. But you definitely should get rid of `groupTimeout` on the aggregator then.

Comment: I just saw that aggregation of messages happens when that group expires - is it possible to do aggregation when message is received? I would like to have this priority re-calculation one message receive, so reaper can just take X messages from head of priority queue? Is there any other way to achieve this thing that I need if using aggregator is overkill?

Comment: Is it possible to use smth like `class PriorityKeyValueMessageStore extends AbstractKeyValueMessageStore implements PriorityCapableChannelMessageStore` ? There is no implementation of this, but I guess I could do aggregation when message arrives at the store. Then store would have some comparator to order by specific priority. Is this an overkill or there is some simpler solution?

Comment: As I said before: the standard aggregator behavior is to release group immediately when sufficient message arrives. The rest are still waiting their messages or expiration callback. So, this looks for me exactly priority you are looking for

Comment: The more I think about it, aggregator looks too complex for this use-case. My aggregation is not based on messages that are split, but on a stream of messages that are received and then merged together - sometimes there is only 1 sometimes 10 messages. I would like to merge those messages as they arrive (since it is much easier to priority-order 1 merged message than group of messages in priority queue). And release strategy is - take current variable throughput (e.g. 10 messages/second) and only release that number of aggregated messages (10) from head of priority queue - so poller polls 10.

Comment: As you can se, I do not have condition to complete the group. It can be complete whenever poller takes it from the head of priority queue. But if it is not released further from priority group, it is still available there to be aggregated. Do you think I could somehow use this PriorityChannel, with some store that would merge messages as they arrive (so not at release time), and then have some poller taking X messages from this channel and forwarding further?

Comment: I updated the question with possible implementation - do you think this could work?

Comment: Probably your custom solution is OK, if that fits to your requirements. However still pay attention to my `expireMessageGroups()` custom impl suggestion. So, you still have a regular aggregator with releasing based only on the repear and in that `expireMessageGroups()` you can decide what to expire (release partially) or reorder according your priority requirements.